# SpringBoot JWT Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, compiler-errors, jwt, dependencies

### Exclusions:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration
```

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```